# Dolphin: custom folder icon (NTFS volume)

Tags: kubuntu, icons, ntfs

if I select a custom icon for a directory within an ext4 volume (e.g. a directory under home), the icon is applied properly. A *.directory* file is created, which contains the path to the icon.

However, if I want to do the same on a directory on a volume mounted as ntfs, the custom icon selected does not show up in Dolphin. R/W access available - also a *.directory* file with the path to the icon is created, but seems to be ignored (at least the icon part of the file).

Is there any possibility to get a custom icon using Dolphin with ntfs volumes?